# Why is (-1 < a.size()) false, even though std::vector's size is positive?

Tags: c++, comparison, stdvector, unsigned, size-t

Please take a look at this simple program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
 
int main() {
    std::vector<int> a;
    std::cout << "vector size " << a.size() << std::endl;
    
    int b = -1;
    if (b < a.size())
       std::cout << "Less";
    else
       std::cout << "Greater";
}
```

The program outputs

> ```
> 0
> Greater
> ```

I am confused by the fact that it outputs `Greater` despite `-1` obviously being less than `0`.

I understand that `size` member function returns an unsigned value, but comparison is still applied to `-1` and `0`, so what's going on?

Comment: -1 unsigned is larger than 0 unsigned due to the high bit being set because it's negative.

Comment: @JesusRamos - or, more abstractly, because the language definition says that values that don't fit in the range of an unsigned type are reduced modulo 2^n, where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type. For twos-complement representations, the most common representation for integral types these days, this is, in fact, because the high bit is set. But other representations are also allowed.

Comment: It's not even about being "abstract"; those are the rules of the language. C++ does not deal in "high bits"; it deals in contract.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the size of a vector is an unsigned integral type. You are comparing an unsigned type with a signed one, and the two's complement negative signed integer is being promoted to unsigned. That corresponds to a large unsigned value.

This code sample shows the same behaviour that you are seeing:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  unsigned int a = 0;
  int b = -1;
  std::cout << (b < a) << "\n"; 
}
```

output:

> false

Answer (score 4):

The signature for `vector::size()` is:

```
size_type size() const noexcept;
```

`size_type` is an **unsigned** integral type. When comparing an unsigned and a signed integer, the signed one is promoted to unsigned. Here, `-1` is negative so it rolls over, effectively yielding the maximal representable value of the `size_type` type. Hence it will compare as greater than zero.

Answer (score 2):

-1 unsigned is a higher value than zero because the high bit is set to indicate that it's negative but unsigned comparison uses this bit to expand the range of representable numbers so it's no longer used as a sign bit. The comparison is done as `(unsigned int)-1 < 0` which is false.

Comment: It's not about "high bits". It's about the rules. And the rules are that -1 converted to an unsigned int wraps around to the top of the unsigned int range. The bitwise representation couldn't be less relevant, even though it conveniently happens to match on many systems.