# Why does the below expression turn out to be true, asking for C++ specifically

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    if(sizeof(int)> -1)
        cout<<"ok";
    else
        cout<<"not ok";

    return 0;
}
```

Isn't size of int supposed to be 4, which should be greater than -1.

Comment: unsigned compared to signed ... `4 > -1` but `4u < unsigned(-1)`.

Comment: I assume it's because 00000004 < FFFFFFFF

Comment: try initializing a size_t variable to -1 and check what happens to it in a debugger

Comment: title says "Why does it turn out to be true" which is the expected...

Comment: [c++ vector size. why -1 is greater than zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16250058/995714), [Why does this if condition fail for comparison of negative and positive integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18247919/995714)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things:

1. `sizeof(int)` can be any positive integral value. (I've worked on a system where `sizeof(char)`, `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(long)` were all 1 and were all 64 bit types.)
2. The *type* returned by `sizeof` is an unsigned type. When comparing with `-1`, `-1` is converted to an unsigned value, with a high magnitude. Almost certainly `sizeof(int)` will be less than that.

Comment: shouldnt `sizeof(int)` be at least 4 to be compliant?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: Nope, the range of `int` needs to be -32767 to +32767. (C++20 widens that by 1). It can be the same range as `char`, if `char` is widened. And `sizeof(char)` *must* be 1.

Comment: The conversion comes from _"[..] if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater than or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, the operand with signed integer type shall be converted to the type of the operand with unsigned integer type."_ ([ref. 8.3 (1.5.3)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf)), isn't it?